# Why does $R^2$ grow when more predictor variables are added to a model?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, r-squared

I do understand that $ R^2 = \frac{\text{SSR}}{\text{SST}}= 1- \frac{SSE}{SST}$, however, I don't understand what changes when more predictor variables are added and how $R^2$ is affected accordingly. Can someone clarify?

Comment: $R^2=1 - \frac{SSR}{SST}$.

Comment: @Antoni it depends on whether you use "R" to stand for "regression" or "residual". Given it's been defined in terms of SSE (implying that SSR+SSE=SST), clearly it's the first rather than the second that is intended.

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks, Glen! I saw it coming that there was an explanation along these lines, the way I was the only one concerned.

Comment: @Antoni unfortunately such incompatible abbreviations abound. Given how widely used stats is, and that people from a variety of areas all don't read each other's writing, large amounts of incompatible jargon is one unsurprising but unfortunate consequence. Thus the constant questions from active commenters asking people to clarify what they mean, even when it might seem obvious.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's suppose that we've got two models:
$$
Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_1 + \varepsilon \tag{M1}
$$
and
$$
Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2 X_2 + \varepsilon \tag{M2}
$$
This means that we have

$$
RSS_1 = \sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i - \hat \beta_0 - \hat \beta_1^{(1)} X_1)^2
$$

and

$$
RSS_2 = \sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i - \hat \beta_0 - \hat \beta_1^{(2)} X_1 - \hat \beta_2 X_2)^2.
$$

Model $M2$ contains model $M1$ as a special case, so there is no way that $RSS_1 < RSS_2$: we can just set $\hat \beta_2 = 0$ and $\hat \beta_1^{(1)} = \hat \beta_1^{(2)}$ in order to get $RSS_1 = RSS_2$. Much more likely is that $RSS_2 < RSS_1$ because we have an extra parameter so we can fit the data more closely.

This reveals the big problem with the unadjusted $R^2$: there is no penalty for model complexity. A more complicated model will almost always fit the data better so $R^2$ will prefer this model, even if the extra complexity is just modeling noise. That's why other methods like the adjusted $R^2$ (as mentioned in Antoni Parellada's answer) and $AIC$ are popular, since these take into account both the fit of the model to the data while also penalizing model complexity.

Comment: Is there a typo in $RSS_2 = \sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i - \hat \beta_0 - \hat \beta_1^{(2)} X_1 - \hat \beta_2 X_2)^2?$ Do you mean $\beta_2^{(2)}$ instead of $\beta_2$?

Comment: +1. Note that numerical funkiness arising from doing calculations on a computer can make this not be true in practice, however.

Answer (score 6):

It is the result of the fitting process that takes place in the OLS regression. Each variable is regressed against all others, and what is left unexplained (residuals) is carried over. In a way, the regression process looks for explanations in the variance in the data, but it doesn't really excel at telling what is signal and what is noise.

In fact, if you were to just include variables composed of random noise, you could still see how there would be progressive overfitting of this noise in a misleading attempt at explaining the variability in the "dependent" variable.

I did this test in [here](https://github.com/RInterested/SIMULATIONS_and_PROOFS/blob/master/R%20squared%20lower%20more%20regressors), and plotted the resulting effect on the $RSS$ as the number of non-sensical variables increased:

[image]

This is why it is advisable to use adjusted $R^2$ instead of $R^2$ to judge whether it is a good idea to include more variables in a model.