# Mathematically, what are the drawbacks of R-squared in evaluation a regression model?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, standard-error, r-squared

I kept seeing articles about the drawbacks of R-squared (and that's why we need to have adjusted R-squared).

One drawback is that: "Every time you add a predictor to a model, the R-squared increases, even if due to chance alone. It never decreases. Consequently, a model with more terms may appear to have a better fit simply because it has more terms." ([link](http://blog.minitab.com/blog/adventures-in-statistics-2/multiple-regession-analysis-use-adjusted-r-squared-and-predicted-r-squared-to-include-the-correct-number-of-variables)).

Mathematically, why does this happen? And mathematically, why adjusted R-squared can solve this problem?

Comment: Check [this](http://thestatsgeek.com/2013/10/28/r-squared-and-adjusted-r-squared/) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/207717/why-does-r2-grow-when-more-predictor-variables-are-added-to-a-model).

Comment: For further analysis on the [problems with R-Squared](https://data.library.virginia.edu/is-r-squared-useless/)

Comment: Perfect @LucasFarias Will them out.

Comment: Also relevant: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/414349/is-my-model-any-good-based-on-the-diagnostic-metric-r2-auc-accuracy-e/414350#414350