# LR test gives contradictory results to R squared

Tags: goodness-of-fit, r-squared, likelihood-ratio

I have a difficult decision here. The R squared suggests that model 1 has a better fit than model 2, but the LR test suggests the model 2 has a better fit. How can I resolve this seemingly contradictory result?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $R^2$ *always* is at least as large when the model is more [complex](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/207717/why-does-r2-grow-when-more-predictor-variables-are-added-to-a-model). The LR test does *not* say if a model has a better fit, but tests if the additional variables are statistically significant in the more general model.

That said, if I interpret your output correctly, the log likelihood of model 2 is larger, so it should have higher $R^2$, and the p-value of the LR test also says that the inclusion is significant. So there does not appear to be a contradaction here. What kind of model are you fitting/can you post a reproducible example?

Comment: How do you figure that the LR test does not say that the more complex model has a better fit?

Comment: I am saying that in the sense of that this is not the null hypothesis of the LR test, but that, I would argue, some coefficient is equal to zero. "Fit" being - I'd say, here - an in-sample criterion, the alternative of better fit would always be true as evidenced by the general result that larger models have higher $R^2$.

Comment: Are you saying the loglikelihood of model 2 -19541 is larger than model 1 -19543, so that model 2's R square should be larger? This is what I was originally saying, but strangely, the model 2 (more complex) R square is 0.220 and less than the model 1 R square of 0.221? @Christoph Hanck I have updated the question with the model. But I still do not understand why this is happening.

Comment: Since your estimates are, now that you post more detailed output, apparently not from a least squares regression, it is not clear how exactly logLik and R^2 are related (or even how R^2 is computed).